# QuerySet and Limit

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am learning Django, and I have a question about queryset performance.
Is code like that:

```
Model.objects.filter('premmium' = True)[:20]
```

Is it equivalent to SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `Model` WHERE `premmium` = True LIMIT 20;
```

Or maybe just a:

```
SELECT * FROM `Model` WHERE `premmium` = True;
```

And then just 20 elements are taken from all?

Comment: `QuerySet` objects have a `.query` attribute, calling `str()` on it or printing it will return the equivalent SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets

It is equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM `Model` WHERE `premmium` = True LIMIT 20;
```

However, it is worth noting that using slices like this is not always the most efficient way of querying because of the way the results are cached (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets)).  Often, if you data set is not huge, it is more efficient to slice in python:

```
list(Model.objects.filter('premmium' = True))[:20]
```